# Android Action Bar Sherlock Illegal Argument Exception after running Proguard

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, apk, proguard

I have just used Proguard for the first time (ever), and having copied the exported APK back into my emulator,

I received an

> ILLEGAL ARGUMENT EXCEPTION : class a is not annotated with
>   @Implementation at com.actionbarsherlock.a.a(Unknown source)

As Proguard appears to have saved me around 400KB, I am keen to use it if possible. Can anybody suggest a good approach here - I don't want to exclude the ABS .jar - my project has grown significantly since starting to use ABS.

Comment: Oh sorry ! Just found something elsewhere posted by Jake Wharton:-keepattributes *Annotation* is required ... (can't close my own questions at present)

Comment: Where did you find it? I can put a close as duplicate request in.

Comment: I was going to tell OP about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624503/noclassdeffounderror-when-using-proguard/13631923#13631923]) I also found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/XQMjPMAPP_4) thread in Google Groups

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add the proguard lines from the ABS website?

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

See http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html