# Android Parcelable problems

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, parcelable

I am having problems marshaling my objects (also implementing Parcelable). I get ClassNotFound exception. and this is code:

```
    public SongManager(Parcel in) {
    try {
        track = in.readParcelable(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        random = new Random();
        shuffle = in.readByte() == 0 ? false : true;
        isTuning = in.readByte() == 0 ? false : true;
        currentTrack = in.readInt();
        currentTrackname = in.readString();
        base = new MusicDatabase(
                MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity.getBaseContext());
        databaseSize = base.databaseSize();
        path = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path, currentTrackname));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(track, 0);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (shuffle?1:0));
    dest.writeByte((byte) (isTuning?1:0));
    dest.writeInt(currentTrack);
    dest.writeString(currentTrackname);
}
```

Main problem is class Song which instance is object track. That's the point where i get exception. Log cat below:

```
12-29 14:29:41.508: E/Parcel(6658): Class not found when unmarshalling: a.b.c.e.d.musicplayer.Song
12-29 14:29:41.508: E/Parcel(6658): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.c.e.d.musicplayer.Song
12-29 14:29:41.508: E/Parcel(6658):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-29 14:29:41.508: E/Parcel(6658):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:305)
12-29 14:29:41.508: E/Parcel(6658):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133)
12-29 14:29:41.508: E/Parcel(6658):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097)
...
```

Comment: It seems you're using Proguard for code obfuscating, so resulting app contains other class names. You should exclude the classes implementing Parcelable from proguard processing. See examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624503/noclassdeffounderror-when-using-proguard) or in the progruard documentation.

Comment: I am not using it explicitly, is there something that is launched for me with it in default?

Comment: Do you have `project.properties` file? Does it contain `proguard.config=...` line? If yes, comment out it.

Comment: I only have target=android-19 in project.properties file